# how to get append mode in sprintf()

Tags: c, string, printf

See this code:

```
int main() {
    char a[50];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("test1.txt", "w");

    sprintf(a,"jigar %d \n", 3);
    fprintf(fp,"jigar %d \n", 3);

    sprintf(a,"patel %d \n", 2);
    fprintf(fp,"patel %d \n", 2);
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Here, using `fprintf`, I can write in file

```
jigar 3 
patel 2
```

where same functionality I want where what ever I print that goes in one char buffer.

but using `sprintf` gives me on buffer

```
patel 2
```

I have so many such print which I want to add in one char buffer and then I need to return it to application so how to get it in **simplest and fastest** way this?

Comment: Manual management of everything in C == pain. But it will be fast, I tell you.

Comment: oh yea sorry it was my typo mistake

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sprintf()` returns the number of characters printed.

Just use that number for the next write ...

```
int i;
char a[50];
char *ap = a;

for (i = 5; i < 15; i++) {
    ap += sprintf(ap, "%d ", i);
}

printf("%s\n", a); /* "5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 " */
```

Make sure you don't cause any buffer overflows though.

Comment: what I do is: int offset = 0; offset += snprintf(ap, sizeof(ap) - offset, ...);

Comment: @Folkert: `snprintf()` assumes C99. Some people are stuck with C89. Good idea though.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden, Basically a good suggestion, but with some bugs. You don't increment `ap`, sizeof(`ap`) is meaningless, and once offset grows too large you'll give `snprintf` a negative size. Better is `offset += snprintf(ap+offset, sizeof(a)>offset?sizeof(a)-offset:0, ...);`.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to give ***sprintf*** the *pointer to the base address of your buffer* + an *offset*. The offset gets bigger while you are appending.

By using *strlen* it is possible to get the lenght of the current 'string'.To avoid a buffer overflow, we could add extra logic in order to check if the current 'string' + 'the new string' is less than the size of the buffer.

```
size_t offset = strlen(text);
sprintf(&(text[offset]), "This is how You append using sprintf");
```

Example within a loop:

```
char text[255];
text[0] = '\0';
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    size_t offset = strlen(text);
    sprintf(&(text[offset]), "%d,", i);
}
```

As from other stackoverflow users suggested, you could also use ***snprintf***, which would give you also buffer overflow protection.

An append function could look like this:

```
void append(char *text, int maxSize, char *toAppend) {
  size_t offset = strlen(text);
  snprintf(&(text[offset]), maxSize, "%s", toAppend);
}
```

Comment: In the example this is true, but if you are passing the buffer to a function which appends some text?

Comment: Fair point, at least one `strlen()` call then needed to find `buffer` end.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a POSIX-compatible system, have a look at [`fmemopen(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) or [`open_memstream(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[128] = { 0 };
    FILE *fp = fmemopen(buf, sizeof(buf), "w");

    assert(fp);

    fprintf(fp, "Hello World!\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%s also work, of course.\n", "Format specifiers");
    fclose(fp);

    puts(buf);
}
```

Comment: Yes something related to my problem. But i wanted to do that using sprintf only..Indeed your way is also good one so +1

Comment: @JeegarPatel I'm curious, what stops you from using fprintf? They have the exact same interface.

Comment: `fmemopen` is defined by POSIX, but not by the C standard.